# Microsoft Teams Content Security Policy Issue

Tags: microsoft-teams

We have an integrated app with Microsoft Teams, when action button clicked the system should redirect to our platform, but we are getting the below error.

Request URL: https://teams.emsigner.com/styles/main.css
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 304 Not Modified
Remote Address: 3.7.14.161:443
Referrer Policy:strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Please guide us to fix this error. Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Sesha

Hi

Request call is blocking the re-direction URL by Content Security Policy (CSP) and getting 304 Not Modified and sometime 200 ok.
The functionality is working for sometime and failing sometime.

Regards,
Sesha

Comment: This means that the browser has cached the resource and doesn't think there have been any changes to it since the last time it was accessed. The app developer should evaluate how they are setting the cache headers on these resources. MDN docs describe this here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/304
 
Also, 304 is not an error. The file is still returned from the local browser cache. MDN has a high level overview of how browser caching works here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching